# Write mapreduce code to search for pattern

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

```
customer_id, server_id, code
12342344, 1232, 3
12345456, 1433, 2
16345436, 2343, 4
12245456, 1434, 3
11145456, 1436, 2
```

If I'm running this query on hive:

```
select * from table where code=3;
```

what would be the code written in mapreduce, where can I find it ?

in another word, how can I write mapreduce job to give the same query results above ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @BigDataLearner for the hint :-)

Comment: If you got an idea from below answer - accept it as an answer (make the correct sign green by clicking on it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run `EXPLAIN select * from table where code=3;` from hive to see hive's query execution plan, but hive doesn't output any mapreduce code for any query. Also check [YSmart-Another SQL-to-MapReduce Translator](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/hpcs/WWW/HTML/publications/papers/TR-11-7.pdf) - to see mapreduce jobs for SQL - I never used it, but you can try it out:

This is sample, you can try to modify for different other queries to get an idea . Basically you will filter the data in map class and run some aggregations in reduce class. but in this example you don't need reduce class as it is simple mapping from data. You will need to go through wordcount (helloworld example of hadooop) first in order to learn how to run this program and where to find output etc.

Output:

```
12245456, 1434, 3   
12342344, 1232, 3
```

Code:

```
public class customers{

    public static class customersMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //this code should be converted to Int - try it for your self
            String code = value.toString().split(",")[2].trim();

            //this line should be chnaged if code variable is converted to Int 
            if (code.equals("3")){ // only map rec where code=3
                context.write(value,new Text(""));
            }       
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "get-customer-with-code=3");

        job.setJarByClass(customers.class);
        job.setMapperClass(customersMapper.class); 
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I saw some answers in different threads where awk was used directly, dfs -cat file | awk -F'|' '$3~/^3/' ..... what would be the difference compared to mapreduce ? @BigDataLearner

Comment: you can use `awk` or any other programming language you are comfortable with using hadoop-streaming. check this articles:
awk-with-hadoop-streaming - http://grepalex.com/2013/01/17/awk-with-hadoop-streaming/
non-java-programs-or-streaming-mapreduce-jobs - https://www.mapr.com/blog/how-using-non-java-programs-or-streaming-mapreduce-jobs
mapreduce-with-awk - http://rishavrohitblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/mapreduce-with-awk.html

Comment: using `awk` directly on hdfs files (without hadoop-streaming) will be ok with smaller files. but for larger file(s) processing and making use of distributed computing power you will need to use `hadoop-streaming` or `mapreduce`.